# Performance with Django querysets

Tags: django, django-queryset

I know querysets are lazy but not sure how Django behave in this case.
Let's say I want to print 2 variables `user_tokens` and `user_last_token`.
Is there a performance difference between these examples:

## Example A

```
@classmethod
def get_all_tokens(cls, user):
    return cls.objects.filter(user=user, usage=cls.PHONE_VALIDATION)

@classmethod
def get_last_token(cls, user):
    return cls.get_all_tokens(user).latest('created_at')

@classmethod
def play_with_tokens(cls, user):
    user_tokens = cls.get_all_tokens(user, True)
    user_last_token = cls.get_last_token(user, True)

    print(user_tokens)
    print(user_last_token)
```

## Example B

```
@classmethod
def get_all_tokens(cls, user):
    return cls.objects.filter(user=user, usage=cls.PHONE_VALIDATION)

@classmethod
def play_with_tokens(cls, user):
    user_tokens = cls.get_all_tokens(user, True)
    user_last_token = user_tokens.latest('created_at')

    print(user_tokens)
    print(user_last_token)
```

Is B faster than A? Thanks.

Comment: it might be a lazy answer, but you can try them both with django-debug-toolbar and evaluate them

Comment: I believe B is faster since the second print statement will not invoke a new database lookup. It will use the cached data from the user_tokens variable.

Answer (score 0):

For DB performance they are the same. You can check it with

```
>>> from django.db import connection, reset_queries
>>> reset_queries()
>>> run your code here...
>>> connection.queries
```

You will see 4 queries: 1st query equals to 3rd one, 2nd query equals to 4th one.

This:

```
user_last_token = user_tokens.latest('created_at')
```

does not use cached queryset, but issues new SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that django querysets are lazy so in both the above cases the query will be executed only when you are printing the values.

Since, both the examples contain two print statements and are printing the same values here, the number of queries and the queries themselves would remain same.

The only difference in the the query for `user_tokens` and `user_last_token` is that the later one would order the tokens based on `created_at` (descending) and take the first one in result.